# Notice: Constant DATE_RFC7231 already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\oxbir\demo\restaurant\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 258

Tags: drupal

What is this error?

> Notice: Constant DATE_RFC7231 already defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\oxbir\demo\restaurant\includes\bootstrap.inc on line
>   258

bootstrap.inc line 258

```
define('DATE_RFC7231', 'D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using `php 7.1` and old `Drupal 7`.

On updated `Drupal 7.x` this error is mitigated.